# How to route log4j messages to unique appenders

Tags: java, logging, log4j

In `log4j` most (if not all) appenders extend `AppenderSkeleton` which provides a `setThreshold(Priority)` method for setting the minimal "level" that a message must be set to in order for the appender to log it somewhere.

I want to log messages to different appenders based on the *exact* level/priority of the message.

For instance, I want DEBUG messages to log to a `ConsoleAppender`, but nowhere else. I want INFO messages to log to a `FileAppender` and nowhere else. I want ERROR messages to log to a `JMSAppender` and nowhere else.

The problem is this `setThreshold(Priority)` method, which sets the "minimal threshold" necessary to log a message.

Sure, I could set the `ConsoleAppender`'s threshold to DEBUG, but since INFO and ERROR messages are "higher" than DEBUG messages, I will also get INFO and ERROR messages sent to the ConsoleAppender as well.

Are there are methods or ways of configuring appender "levels"/priorities *exactly* or is this minimal threshold my only recourse?

**Edit using LevelMatchFilter**:

Is this a step in the right direction?

```
LevelMatchFilter filter = new LevelMatchFilter();
filter.setLevelToMatch(Level.DEBUG.toString());

consoleAppender.addFilter(filter);
```

Would that code snippet above accomplish the job of making sure the `ConsoleAppender` logs DEBUGs, and *only* DEBUGs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a [LevelMatchFilter](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/LevelMatchFilter.html) to any appender to filter log messages by only the exact level.

From the javadoc:

This is a very simple filter based on level matching.

The filter admits two options `LevelToMatch` and `AcceptOnMatch`. If there is an exact match between the value of the `LevelToMatch` option and the level of the `LoggingEvent`, then the `decide(org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent)` method returns `Filter.ACCEPT` in case the `AcceptOnMatch` option value is set to true, if it is false then `Filter.DENY` is returned. If there is no match, `Filter.NEUTRAL` is returned.

Comment: Thanks jalopaba - please take a look at my edited (added) code snippet and let me know if I'm using it incorrectly. Thanks again!